# Heatmap with calendR

Tags: r, data-visualization

Newbie here, I am having an issue creating a heatmap with the following data (365 variables)
The error is:

```
"Error in calendR(year = 2021, special.days = Events11, gradient = TRUE,  : 
  No element of the 'special.days' vector can be greater than the number of days of the corresponding month or year"
```

The only time it seems to work is when "special.days = 1:365" for some reason, can anyone help?

```
Events11 <- c(879,1997,2122,2767,3334,3425,3373,3353,4352,2882,2964,3686,3922,3152,3536,2819,2110,3101,2687,2290,3678,2658,3004,2586,2586,1089,1922,2254,2769,1844,368,1516,1973,2292,1430,1064,663,521,844,1176,1112,1163,1544,582,459,312,221,494,645,782,907,737,1275,2485,2821,2829,3515,6612,3022,3010,3647,5073,3579,4840,6149,5813,8150,9511,6704,6938,6499,11675,4833,1952,3797,3342,3275,5974,11779,15132,10208,4661,7376,5427,5538,11605,6663,8053,8828,5658,4812,8217,17934,15919,10248,15543,14057,4645,11047,4764,9813,9884,8937,7373,7613,9728,12547,11891,5883,5561,5671,9492,11812,13328,7717,12754,16214,5780,8443,10576,21690,22206,8531,7884,10692,8006,11233,12929,6071,7876,9380,11428,14119,17265,13049,20364,12795,10549,13406,17304,20889,30104,18677,16910,15846,17105,9676,5682,18111,22761,18455,16354,17081,19631,21521,30320,24527,14793,18815,20676,21281,24869,28841,29919,19366,20332,21539,21771,23542,31261,18387,17988,20929,19720,12373,13415,11694,24158,13381,14631,15659,20661,22326,28036,28086,23317,19473,19109,19031,24713,20944,10558,16633,19040,21134,17094,19541,31877,27352,19866,21586,21290,21986,21712,27321,26976,20321,21349,22253,22841,24917,30966,25601,19443,20559,21065,21927,22585,30466,23038,14026,17085,17844,20310,24250,32693,26920,19540,20916,21128,21063,23518,26588,25821,19457,14416,16899,21696,22544,25713,19766,18540,18968,20954,20616,19491,23345,28157,24786,15904,20167,20770,22116,28073,22788,17766,19359,20847,22395,21727,27347,23476,15968,14458,13638,16652,19825,24884,21715,17256,18275,19135,19228,21720,19814,15708,14377,16425,16943,13247,16907,27027,25335,10716,15976,14720,16662,16007,20841,19649,16428,18308,17843,13039,14957,17318,3700,6407,13638,14054,7826,4673,14996,12711,10619,10775,10815,10800,11542,13998,13985,12741,12248,12649,8324,6884,7688,4925,7070,10035,8261,7648,8192,9358,7975,6196,6926,6387,2785,3155,4468,4491,6375,8552,8766,10617,9641,8539,3107,5466,5286,6626,7755,5675,5902,6524,7365,8356,9047,6872,6544,4375,4227,5613,5041,3697,4320,3224,2266,2733,3521,2042,3931,4604,4689)

calendR(year = 2021,
    special.days = Events11,
    gradient = TRUE,
    special.col = rgb(1, 0, 0, alpha = 0.6), 
    low.col = "white")
```

Answer (score 2):

```
"Error in calendR(year = 2021, special.days = Events11, gradient = TRUE,  : 
  No element of the 'special.days' vector can be greater than the number of days of the corresponding month or year"
```

This is due to the way calendR do with scale - they restricted the values of element to no greater than 365. What you can do is normalize the input to a scale that in acceptable range no greater than 365 for a year or 3x days for a month.

Here is an example

```r
library(calendR)

# a scale function that always have the value between 0 - 1 
scale_fn <- function(x) { x / sqrt(sum(x^2)) }
# normalized your data
Events11_normalized <- scale_fn(Events11)

calendR(year = 2021,
        special.days = Events11_normalized,
        gradient = TRUE,
        special.col = rgb(1, 0, 0, alpha = 0.6), 
        low.col = "white")
```

And here the `calendR` work just fine.

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-01-26 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: This was perfect! Seems that i had missed just that part! Thank you Sinh!

Comment: @YousefMenesy It this worked for you why did you accept the answer?